# Add custom information in popup labels: geoExploreR

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, rstudio, ggvis

I am new to Shiny, and I am playing with geoExplorer. This app combines reactive ggvis and Leaflet.

When you click in a data point, there is a popup label including information on the input variables that we may choose: **https://github.com/davesteps/geoExploreR**

My question is: how can I include in this program additional information for the clicked point besides the input/output? and example would be to add an identifier for the point we click, which may be included in the same or a secondary dataframe.

Hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

The function you are looking `addPopups()`, or if you want to attach popups to markers in a leaflet, use the `popup` argument in a marker command. For example, if you're making a map from data stored in a spatial points data frame called `mydat`, and you wanted to include the columns of data V1:V5 as text within your popup, your code might look something like:

```
map = leaflet(data = mydat) 
map = addTiles(map)
map %>%
    addCircleMarkers(map,
        lng = longitude, # longitude
        lat = latitude, # latitude
        radius = 4, # fixed radius size
        color = ~pal(Result),
        popup = paste(mydat$Var1, " more text", "<br>",
              "Var2: ", mydat$Var2, "<br>",
              "Var3: ", mydat$Var3, "<br>",
              "Var4: ", mydat$Var4, "<br>",
              "Var5: ", mydat$Var5))
      )
```

You can customize the text in your popup window such that it displays data from your data frame.

A great (but limited) resource is the Leaflet by R webpage covering popups: https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/popups.html

Here's a personal example of leaflet where I use popups displaying lot of information.
 http://rpubs.com/richpauloo/Tulare_maps_v2. There's a link to a github repo where you can view the source data and run it yourself.